# WPF / MVVM: Show specific image from list of images?

Tags: wpf, image, mvvm, imagelist

I have two lists of different object types in my ViewModel. For example I'd say the first one is a list of all available images, the second one is a list of all articles. Each article belongs to an article category for which I'd like to show a thumbnail in the GUI when an article is selected and shown. For the sake of a simple example I assume that the Id of the category equals the Id of the corresponding image.

For a ComboBox this would be an easy task: I would assing the list of all images as ItemSource and then the article's category key to the SelectedValue. The SelectedValuePath would have to point to the Id of the image.
However a ComboBox does not make sense here as I only want to display the correct category image - I do not want any editing, a dropdown, etc... How would I solve this with a regular Image-UserControl (or maybe a similar UserContro)?

BTW: Right now I have to use an additional Property on my Article class which directly holds the correct image, but I think there should be a better way to solve this issue.

Any ideas?

Regards

ralf

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with creating a get-only property on your ViewModel that provides the image that the view should bind to.  The whole point of ViewModels is to shape model data into a structure suitable for binding views to.

Comment: For this solution each and every article object would need a reference to the images list in order to expose the corresponding image. I'd like to keep it simple and maybe someone has a nice idea how to make it more simple.